# Splitting monolith to microservices database issues

Tags: database, oracle, join, microservices

I am splitting monolith application to microservices and I was able to split it to three microservices, for easier explanation suppose these are:

- Users (CRUD)
- Messages (CRUD)
- Other things (CRUD)

All of these are distinct bounded contexts and I'm using database table for microservice. So in DB i have:

```
USERS table
id
surname
lastname
...

OTHER_THINGS table
id
col1
col2
...

MESSAGES table
id
title
created_time
USER_ID
OTHER_THING_ID
...
```

Now my web page needs searching/filtering of messages by all of the specified columns of all of these tables. For example:

Web page user can enter:

- surname of USER,
- col2 of OTHER_THINGS
- title of messages

And I should return only filtered rows.

With monolith I have used simple database JOINS, but in this situation I can't find the best option. Can you suggest me possible options and which ones are better?

Comment: Why did you split the application along the *DB tables*?! Especially since you have foreign key relations between them? This does not seem to make much sense. Rethink your approach to see *if* and *where* microservices make sense in your case. - Otherwise you may have to come up with another service for the more complex querying.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, this is an example, in my case these three are distinct bounded contexts(they also contains more tables, I just need searching/filtering like that for three tables of them). For me these three microservices are correct from microservices perspective.
And about another service for complex queyring, how it should work? SELECT filtered id's from USERS? Then SELECT filtered id's from OTHER_THINGS and then SELECT filtered messages using earlier id's of USERS and OTHER_THINGS?

Comment: How can it be a "bounded context" if there are foreign key relations between them, and you need operations accessing all the "contexts" together? - You could write another service with a search operation which uses plain SQL joins &c. across the tables to provide the search result.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what a microservice is. Your web-page is one microservice with one data store that includes *all the data* required.

Comment: Don't go too deeply to my example about bounded context. 
Ok let's make it simpler, suppose I have Orders and Customers tables, where ORDER has FK to CUSTOMER. For me these seems to be in different microservices. And what if I want to have a page where I can find customers by customer name and order date?

Comment: I would not be using CRUD as the decomposition of a monolith to microservices, ruther use the bounded context to find the things that belong together regardless of your data model, once you find these units of work then worry about you data... and as @APC said, no referential integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "suppose I have Orders and Customers tables, where ORDER has FK to CUSTOMER. For me these seems to be in different microservices. "

Still nope to the foreign key. The Orders microservice  has a data store with its own Customers table. The Customer Update microservice has a data store with its own Customers table. The Customer Orders search would be a feature of the Orders microservice and so will search its data store not the Customer Update data store.

The whole point about microservices is the absence of dependencies. They are entire, discrete systems in the their own right. This makes them easy to build and easy to deploy. The snag is the issue you are butting up against: data management. Most enterprises aspire to a single source of truth regarding their data. Which usually means a central database, which imposes constraints on applications because everything has to share the same data model and changes to common entities such as Customer cause major upheaval.

Microservices appear to offer a solution to this by spinning out subsets of functionality which own their own data model. This inevitably means data integrity across the enterprise is looser, because it is handled asynchronously. There is no longer a single source of truth.

So the Customer Update microservice will publish updates about Customers as messages which the Orders microservice will consume and apply. Likewise, if the Orders microservice can create new Customers then it will publish a similar stream of messages which the Customer Update microservice will consume and apply. What happens if the two microservices create records for the same new Customer in the same window between refreshes? Well, yes, a good question.

The upshot is, the microservice will work in some scenarios and be absolutely disastrous in others. Certainly most enterprise applications will remain largely monolithic not just through inertia but because the benefits of centrally shared data outweigh the agility of microservices in many instances.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
"So the Customer Update microservice will publish updates about Customers as messages which the Orders microservice will consume and apply. Likewise, if the Orders microservice can create new Customers then it will publish a similar stream of messages which the Customer Update microservice will consume and apply."
So you are talking about event-source pattern? If yes, can someone suggest me some implementation of it? I'm using Spring Boot.